# Python: can a variable take two different strings?

Tags: python, string, variables

Am I being dumb here?

I would like to know if I have a list called `cons=['gps-ops', 'beidou']` and in my code there are different names for the same thing. i.e: `'gps-ops' = 'GPS'` and `'beidou'='BDS'`.

Some parts of the code (class) takes 'gps-ops' and some parts take 'GPS'. At the moment I have been using `if` and `elif` statements at different sections of the code.

Is there a way to say 'gps-ops' is also 'GPS' and vice versa, depending on how the user inputs the string throughout the code?

Comment: `'gps-ops'` and `'GPS'` are two different strings. so the `==` comparison operator will fail. You need to add `or` check in your if statements like `if (var == 'gps-ops') or (var == 'GPS')` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could put every word for each valid name in a set like `{'gps-ops', 'GPS'}` and then go through your list in a for loop and check if that word is in the set:

```
gps_set = {'gps-ops', 'GPS'}
for name in cons:
  if name in gps_set:
     # do somehthing if true
```

Read the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) for sets, they're quite an amazing data structure